# Joomla Comonent update data

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I'm working on a Joomla 3 component. Currently I'm programming the backend. I'm having a form to add new data and it is working quite well. But when I want to update the data the component creates a new item instead of updating the existing. 
I was searching for position which let Joomla know, that this is an update, but without success.

So my question: what is the information that makes Joomla updating the data?

My Code:
Table:**ia.php**

```
class mkTableia extends JTable
{
        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param object Database connector object
         */
        function __construct(&$db) 
        {
                parent::__construct('#__tbl_ia', 'ID', $db);
        }
}
```

**Model: ia.php**

```
class mkModelia extends JModelAdmin
{

        public function getTable($type = 'ia', $prefix = 'mkTable', $config = array()) 
        {
                return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
        }

        public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) 
        {
                // Get the form.
                $form = $this->loadForm('com_mk.ia', 'ia',
                                        array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
                if (empty($form)) 
                {
                        return false;
                }
                return $form;
        }

        protected function loadFormData() 
        {
                // Check the session for previously entered form data.
                $data = JFactory::getApplication()->getUserState('com_mk.edit.ia.data', array());
                if (empty($data)) 
                {
                        $data = $this->getItem();
                }
                return $data;
        }
}
```

**View:view.html.php**

```
class mkViewia extends JViewLegacy
{
        /**
         * display method of Hello view
         * @return void
         */
        public function display($tpl = null) 
        {
                // get the Data
                $form = $this->get('Form');
                $item = $this->get('Item');

                // Check for errors.
                if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors'))) 
                {
                        JError::raiseError(500, implode('<br />', $errors));
                        return false;
                }
                // Assign the Data
                $this->form = $form;
                $this->item = $item;

                // Set the toolbar
                $this->addToolBar();

                // Display the template
                parent::display($tpl);
        }

        /**
         * Setting the toolbar
         */
        protected function addToolBar() 
        {
                $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
                $input->set('hidemainmenu', true);
                $isNew = ($this->item->ID == 0);

                JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? JText::_('COM_MK_MANAGER_MK_NEW')
                                             : JText::_('COM_MK_MANAGER_MK_EDIT'));
                JToolBarHelper::save('IA.save');
                JToolBarHelper::cancel('IA.cancel', $isNew ? 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL'
                                                                   : 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you really using ID instead of id?  You should get an update if the primary key != 0, try dumping out your data before the `save()` and see what it says.

Comment: One possibility is that there is no hidden field with "ID" name.Your form data will only update if there is any ID variable in request if not it will create a new entry in the table.

Comment: Also ID should be zero for new entry and if you want to update it should be respective ID column value of data which you want to update.